# Looking for a appropraite logic

Tags: java, android, database

Actually I am using call logs as an input to database and then I am fetching it in a way that I can't get any duplicate values while displaying it and if i have any duplicate value in data base then it should be taken as integer value count. For example: john(6).
Here john must have entry 6 times in database. Don't get me wrong. I don't need a code.I need help. Here is code:

```
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cur = cr.query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

         while (cur.moveToNext()) {
     String rawContactId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID));
    Cursor callLogCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{

                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE
            },android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID + "=?", new String[] { rawContactId }, null);;

      if (callLogCursor != null) {
        while (callLogCursor.moveToNext()) {
            //String id = callLogCursor.getString(0);
            String name = callLogCursor.getString(0);
            String cacheNumber = callLogCursor.getString(1);
            String number = callLogCursor.getString(2);
            long dateTimeMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(3);
            long durationMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(4);
            int callType = callLogCursor.getInt(5);

            String duration = getDuration(durationMillis * 1000);

            String dateString = getDateTime(dateTimeMillis);


            if (cacheNumber == null)
                cacheNumber = number;
            if (name == null)
                name = "Unknown";
            Uri image = null;

            try {
                String conId = fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(cacheNumber);
                long contId = Long.parseLong(conId);
                image = getPhotoUri(contId);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }


                //CallLogModel callLogModel = new CallLogModel(image, name, cacheNumber,
                    //  duration, dateString);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(NAME, name);
                values.put(NUMBER, cacheNumber);
                values.put(DATE, dateString);
                values.put(DURATION,duration );
                database.insert(CALL_LOG_TABLE, null, values);

                Cursor cursor = database.query(CALL_LOG_TABLE, new String [] {LOG_ID, NAME, NUMBER, DATE, DURATION}, null, null, null, null, null);

                int row =0;
                if(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    do{

                        int pId=cursor.getInt(0);
                        String pName = cursor.getString(1);
                        String pNumber = cursor.getString(2);
                        String pDate = cursor.getString(3);
                        String pDuration = cursor.getString(4);
                        int value = 0;

                        CallLogModel callLogModel = new CallLogModel(image, name, cacheNumber, duration, dateString);

                        if (callType == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
                            for(int i=0;i<outgoingList.size();i++){
 ------------------------------Actually i want Logic here what should i do here--------------

                                }
                            }
                            outgoingList.add(callLogModel);

                        } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE) {
                            incomingList.add(callLogModel);

                        } else if (callType == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
                            missedcallList.add(callLogModel);

                        }

                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    } while (!cursor.isAfterLast());
                }





        }

        callLogCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could model the outgoing calls in a hashmap, something like:

```
    Map<String, Integer> outgoingCallsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < outgoingList.size(); i++) {
        String nameOfCallee = outgoingList.get(i);
        if (!outgoingCallsMap.containsKey(nameOfCallee)) {
            outgoingCallsMap.put(nameOfCallee, 1);
        } else {
            //Increment calls to this person
            outgoingCallsMap.put(nameOfCallee, outgoingCallsMap.get(nameOfCallee) + 1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @aquaraga..."outgoingList.get(i)" will return name,number,date,duration and i don't think all these could be same anytime..

Comment: @user3101598 What is outgoingList composed of? I thought they are strings. In case the list has some other objects of type, say, Foo; your nameOfCallee will be outgoingList.get(i).getName();

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicates in your outGoingList, by iterating it and putting the result to a map, with contact name as key and list of CallLogModel object as value.
You can refer this method.

```
private void convertToOutGoingMap(List<CallLogModel > outGoingList) {
        HashMap<String,List<CallLogModel>> outGoingMap = new HashMap<String, List<CallLogModel>>();//map which has CallLogModel.name as key and List<CallLogModel> as value.
        for(CallLogModel model : outGoingList){//Iterate thru the list.
            if(outGoingMap.containsKey(model.name))
            {
                outGoingMap.get(model.name).add(model);//if map contains key, add model to the list.
            } else {
                List<CallLogModel> modelList = new ArrayList<CallLogModel>();//if it does not contains, initialize a list and add model to it.
                modelList.add(model);
                outGoingMap.put(model.name, modelList);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The key set of this map gives you the unique call log names and corresponding value list gives all occurrences and its size gives you number of occurrences.

Hope this help you.